# C# string split into one or two variables

Tags: c#

In C# I am passing a single string value to a function. The value is similar to this: `"XA=12345678;BK=AZ31"` or `"XA=87654321"`, sometimes the `BK=` is there, sometimes it is not. But if it's present, I need it for my function.

I've made this attempt:

```
string[] item_list = { "XA=12345678;BK=AZ31", "XA=87654321" };
string XA_EQ = "";
string BK_EQ = "";
foreach(string item in item_list)
{
    BK_EQ = "";
    string[] split = item.Split(';');
    XA_EQ = split[0];
    if(split.length == 2)
        BK_EQ = split[1];
    my_func(XA_EQ, BK_EQ);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? This works, but it seems inconvenient.

Comment: Seems like your code isn't compiling and is missing something but I could see a problem since BK_EQ isn't reset on each loop.

Comment: yeah, it looks like `BK_EQ` should be set to `split[1]` too, not the nonexistent `lot` variable

Comment: This can be done many ways, but more than likely will generate many opinion based answers of which all *could work be a good choice*... How would you pick one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RegEx approach

```
string[] item_list = { "XA=12345678;BK=AZ31", "XA=87654321" };
foreach (string item in item_list)
{
    string XA_EQ = Regex.Match(item, "(?<=XA=)[0-9A-Z]*").Value;
    string BK_EQ = Regex.Match(item, "(?<=BK=)[0-9A-Z]*").Value;
    my_func(XA_EQ, BK_EQ);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6xgBi3

Comment: Didn't think of Regex. This works like a charm

Comment: `(?<=XA=)[0-9A-Z]*|(?<=BK=)[0-9A-Z]*` one go and fewer steps, thoughts?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ could you update my fiddle? I'm not sure about that approach

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `Split`ting initial `string`s into `Dictionary`:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static Dictionary<string, string> GetVariables(string source) {
  return source
    .Split(';')
    .Select(pair => pair.Split('='))
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair[0].Trim(), pair => pair[1].Trim());
}
```

Now we can analyze values:

```
string[] item_list = new string[] { "XA=12345678;BK=AZ31", "XA=87654321" };  

foreach(string item in item_list) {
  var namesAndValues = GetVariables(item);

  // If we have XA variable, assign its value to XA_EQ, otherwise assign ""
  string XA_EQ = namesAndValues.TryGetValue("XA", out string xa) ? xa : "";

  // If we have "BK" variable, call my_func with it
  if (namesAndValues.TryGetValue("BK", out string BK_EQ)) {
    // If we have "BK" variable
    my_func(XA_EQ, BK_EQ);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy to read solution with LINQ:

```
   string[] itemList = { "XA=12345678;BK=AZ31", "XA=87654321" };
   itemList.Select(x => x.Split(";")).ToList().ForEach(i =>
            {
                string XA_EQ = i.FirstOrDefault();
                string BK_EQ = i.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
                my_func(XA_EQ,  BK_EQ != null ? BK_EQ : "");
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't get the actual value of `XA` or `BK` this way, but since you mention that this works for you I'm implementing the same logic.

```
string[] item_list = { "XA=12345678;BK=AZ31", "XA=87654321" };
foreach(string item in item_list)
{
    if item.Contains('BK') {
       string[] split = item.split(';');
       my_func(split[0], split[1]);
    } else {
      my_func(item, null);
    }

}
```